# How can I find the point where a line intersects at a specific distance? (from (0,0)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image: Graph]

I'm trying to find the point $(x_3, y_3)$, where line 2 $(y_2 = m_2x_2)$ crosses line 1 $(y_1 = m_1x_1 + c_1)$ such that the distance from $(0,0)$ is a specific distance $a$

I'll know line1 (slope and y intersection), line2 is unknown but I know what $a$ is. I realise there are two solutions (with another point being in lower left quadrant, with same distance $a$, not drawn). So I'm thinking:

Substitute y to get formula for the intersection between lines1&2: $$x_3 = \frac{- c_1}{m_1 - m_2}$$

I also know that $$a = \sqrt{(x_3^2 + y_3^2)}$$

So (I think this is right) I could end up with:
$$a = \sqrt{(\frac{- c_1}{m_1 - m_2})^2 + (m_1x_1 + c_1)^2}$$
If I can rearrange so that I have $m_2$ on one side, then I can replace that in to my intersection formula: I wouldn't have any unknowns so I could find $x_3$ and then derive $y_3$.

Getting $m_2$ on one side of the equation would be a bit tricky but I can try to figure that out (if someone can please verify that's possible!) I also thought maybe I just think of $a$ as a radius around $(0,0)$ and look in to a formula for a line intersecting a circle. Or is there a third simpler solution I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is close.  You have two equations in two unknowns:
$$y=mx+c\\x^2+y^2=a^2$$  Substitute the first into the second
$$x^2+(mx+c)^2=a^2\\(m^2+1)x^2+2cmx+c^2-a^2=0$$ and appeal to the quadratic formula to get$$x=\frac 1{m^2+1}\left(-cm\pm\sqrt{c^2m^2+a^2(m^2+1)}\right)$$.

Comment: forgive me.... is that right? Wouldn't it be x^2 + (mx)^2 + 2cmx + c^2 - a^2 = 0?

I don't understand the simplification from x^2 + (mx)^2 to (m^2 + 1)x^2...

Comment: nevermind... I can see that simplification works (I was miscalculating somewhere). Still curious how that works though? My algebra is clearly not up to scratch :)

Comment: The first equation is the line, the second is a circle of radius $a$ centered at the origin.  When you solve them simultaneously, you are finding the points of intersection.

Comment: ah yes of course! I was thinking just in terms of Pythagoras but makes sense that would also be the formula for a circle (somewhere my old maths teacher is turning in his grave. Also see that (mx)^2 = m*x*m*x = m*m*x*x = m^2*x^2. Perhaps that was the thing that made him turn actually ;) Thanks heaps!

Comment: I believe you meant to have $a^2$ everywhere rather than $a$.

Comment: @Aweygan:  Correct.  Thanks.  I believe it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely isolate $m_2$ in your last equation.  Another approach would be to look for the points on the line $y=m_1x+c_1$ whose distance from the origin is $a$.  That is, look for $x$ such that 
$$ (y-0)^2+(x-0)^2=(m_1x+c_1)^2+x^2=a^2 $$
and find solutions to the corresponding  polynomial.